# Core data not saving item

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Core Data problem - while I'm saving item he put details of the old item
and not saving details of new item.

how i can fix it?

**MenuViewcontroller:**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Pass");
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UpdateItem"]) {
        SmartWishList *selectedDevice = [self.SmartWishList objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]row]];
        AddItemViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.selectedDevice = selectedDevice;

    }
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

-(void)fetchObjects{
    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"SmartWishList"];
    self.SmartWishList = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
}
```

**Additemviewcontroller:**

```
    - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context =nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (self.selectedDevice) {
        // Update existing device

        [self.selectedDevice setValue:self.titleTextField.text forKey:@"title"];
        [self.selectedDevice setValue:self.webTextField.text forKey:@"website"];
        [self.selectedDevice setValue:self.priceTextField.text forKey:@"price"];
        [self.selectedDevice setValue:[self.priceTextField currencySignString] forKey:@"currency"];
    } else {


        // Create a new managed object
        NSManagedObject *newItem = [NSEntityDescription  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SmartWishList" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newItem setValue:self.titleTextField.text forKey:@"title"];
        [newItem setValue:self.webTextField.text forKey:@"website"];
        [newItem setValue:self.priceTextField.text forKey:@"price"];
        [newItem setValue:[self.priceTextField currencySignString] forKey:@"currency"];
    }


    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([[self managedObjectContext] save:&error] == NO) {
        NSAssert(NO, @"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
-(void)ChangeColorPlaceHolder:(UITextField *)textField withText:(NSString *)text andColor:(UIColor *)color
{

    textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:text attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color}];


}
- (IBAction)SegmentControl:(id)sender {
    NSInteger selectedIndex = ((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex;
    [self.priceTextField setCurrency:(CurrencySign)selectedIndex];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"Update item");

    if (self.selectedDevice) {
        // Update existing device
        self.title = self.selectedDevice.title;
        [self.titleTextField setText:self.selectedDevice.title];
        [self.webTextField setText:self.selectedDevice.website];

        [self.priceTextField setText:self.selectedDevice.price];
        [self.priceTextField setCurrecnySign:self.selectedDevice.currency];

        [self.segmentController setSelectedSegmentIndex:(NSInteger)self.priceTextField.currency];

    }



}
```

Thank you for help! how i can fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i can suggest a solution:
instead of :

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
```

use this:

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[self getAppDelegate] managedObjectContext];
```

to support this solution, please add the method:

```
-(AppDelegate *)getAppDelegate{
return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

}

(import the AppDelegate.h)

and now, please add this method:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}
return _managedObjectContext;
```

}

in the AppDelegate.m

now, verify that all of your project has this method calls to get the context.

and do not forget when you have open any new view (for example select any row from table view), to read the relevant row from Core data.

this was my first mistake and i have spent a couple of days to understand the wrong view.

i hope the will helpful